# How to clear cookies in Sencha Touch 2.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework, sencha-touch-2

Upon logging in to server-side assets, the server sets cookies in my sencha touch app. In order to 'logout' I need to clear those cookies client side but I can't figure out how to do that. In JQuery I would do something like this:

```
$.cookie('cookiename', null)
```

When I try something that I *think* is equivalent in my Sencha app it does not work (I can still see the cookies in the next Ajax request I make).

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch does not provide a helper for you. You will need to use native JavaScript methods directly to do this.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: I am either not implementing this right or this does not work. The use case is this. I send a request from fresh state (no cookies). The server set a cookie with name 'alpha'. I issue a eraseCookie('alpha') using the code from the url you referenced. On the very next request to the same server, the request automatically contains cookie 'alpha' with the value that came back from server on the previous request. The cookie is still there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [Ext.util.Cookies class from Ext JS 4.1](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Cookies.html#Ext-util-Cookies).
While not every Ext JS 4 class is necessarily compatible with Sencha Touch 2, this one worked for me.
When using this class in your project, be aware that Ext JS has a different license than Sencha Touch.